# How to aid Scala in type inference?

Tags: scala, type-inference

Sometimes Scala has trouble inferring the types. The goal here is to understand why and try to help Scala to do better inference.

The problem is better explained with a simple example:

```
trait A
trait B

class G[Ao <: A, Bo <: B](a: Ao, b: Bo)

// This is my "complex" class with 3 type parameters
class X[Ao <: A, Bo <: B, Go <: G[Ao,Bo]](a: Ao, b: Bo, g: Go)

val a  = new A{}
val b  = new B{}
val g  = new G(a,b)
```

Here the type of OO below is **perfectly inferred**:

```
class OO extends X(a,b,g) // Type of X[A,B,G[A,B]]
```

However, if we change one of the arguments to be an option (or any collection that is), and we provide an empty collection (or None) then inference doesn't work.

```
case class X[Ao <: A, Bo <: B, Go <: G[Ao,Bo]](a: Ao, b: List[Bo], g: Go)

class OO extends X(a,List(),g)

<console>:XX: error: inferred type arguments [A,Nothing,G[A,B]] do not conform to class X's type parameter bounds [Ao <: A,Bo <: B,Go <: G[Ao,Bo]]
       class OO extends X(a,List(),g)
                        ^
<console>:XX: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: Ao
       class OO extends X(a,List(),g)
                          ^
<console>:XX: error: type mismatch;
 found   : G[A,B]
 required: Go
       class OO extends X(a,List(),g)
```

This can be fixed by explicitly passing all the parameters of OO like this:

```
class OO extends X[A,B,G[A,B]](a,List(),g)
```

The thing is, G already has its types, and from the definition of X we see that G takes the first two parameters of X, so if we know G we have everything we need to infer the parameters of X. **Can I do something different to help Scala with the inference?** I have a class that has much more parameters than X and now I always have to explicitly define them. I am trying to see if there is something I can do to help Scala successfully infer the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could use higher kinded types:

```
case class X[Ao <: A, Bo <: B, Go[GAo <: Ao, GBo <: Bo] <: G[GAo, GBo]](a: Ao, b: List[Bo], g: Go[Ao, Bo])
class OO extends X(a,List(),g)
```

or, if your type parameters are covariant:

```
case class G[+Ao <: A, +Bo <: B](a: Ao, b: Bo)
case class X[Ao <: A, Bo <: B, Go[_ <: Ao, _ <: Bo] <: G[Ao, Bo]](a: Ao, b: List[Bo], g: Go[Ao, Bo])
```

I know from experience that the scala compiler can't infer types from parameters of the same group when they depend on each other on "different levels" like in this example. A higher kinded type allows me to explicitly declare type bounds and help the compiler infer the right types.

Comment: This looks promising! Let me check it out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your reasoning? What made you think of higher minded types?

Comment: I added a (sort of) explanation to the answer. I guess someone more experienced with type systems and functional programming could explain why it works better than me. I only know from experience that the compiler can't infer type parameters in these cases and you have to "help" it by specifying bounds like I did. Sorry I couldn't help more :)